# How can I test an Angular 2 ErrorHandler implementation?

Tags: angular, testing

I have overridden the @angular/core ErrorHandler and I am trying to test it, however I am getting an error. The service works properly but the test fails somewhere.

**exception-handler.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, ErrorHandler, forwardRef, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { BkHttp } from './http.service';

@Injectable()
export class BkExceptionHandlerService implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor( private bkHttp: BkHttp) { }

  handleError(error) {
    let originalError = this.controlError(error);

    this.sendToConsole(originalError);
    this.sendToBitacora( originalError );
    throw( error );


  }

  controlError(error: any): any {
    let originalError: Object =  this.findOriginalError( error );
    return originalError;
  }

  findOriginalError( error: any ) : any {
    while ( error && error.originalError ) {
        error = error.originalError;
    }
    return( error );
  }


  getPrueba():string {
    return 'prueba!!!';
  }

  sendToConsole(error:any): void {
    try {
      console.group( 'START ErrorHandler' );
      console.error( error );
      console.error( error.message );
      console.error( error.stack );
      console.groupEnd();
    } catch (handlingError) {
      console.group( 'START ErrorHandler' );
      console.warn( 'Error when trying to output error. Pure Irony' );
      console.error( handlingError );
      console.groupEnd();
    }
  }

  sendToBitacora(error:any): void {
    let body: Object = {
      name: error.name,
      message: error.message,
      stack: error.stack,
      location: window.location.href
    };


    this.bkHttp.post('http://google.es', body).subscribe(res => { });

    //this.bkHttp.post('http://fgooffglffffe.es', body);




  }
}
```

**An here it is the test file**

```
import { Component, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }           from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Response, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { BkHttp } from './http.service';

import { BkExceptionHandlerService }  from './exception-handler.service';
const ERROR_MESSAGE = 'Dummy Error';

@Component({
  selector: 'dummy-component',
  template: `<button (click)="throwError()">Throw an error!!!</button>`
})
export class MockComponent {

  public throwError(): void {
    throw Error(ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }

}


describe('FancyService without the TestBed', () => {
  let bkExceptionHandlerService: BkExceptionHandlerService;
  let bkHttp: BkHttp;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MockComponent>;

  let loggerSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  let consoleSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  let errorObservableSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  let comp: MockComponent;


beforeEach( async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [ MockComponent ],
        })
        .compileComponents(); // compile template and css

      }));
  beforeEach(() => {
    bkExceptionHandlerService = new BkExceptionHandlerService(bkHttp);

    loggerSpy  = spyOn(bkExceptionHandlerService, 'controlError').and.callThrough();
    consoleSpy = spyOn(console, 'error');

    errorObservableSpy = jasmine.createSpy('log event observable subscription');
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MockComponent);

    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MockComponent);

  });

  it('should log error to the console', () => {
      let elem = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
      elem.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
      expect(loggerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Error), ERROR_MESSAGE);
  });
});
```

**And finally the error**

```
Error: Error in ./MockComponent class MockComponent - inline template:0:0 caused by: Dummy Error in node_modules/@bankular/development-tools/config/karma-test-shim.js (line 49231)
```

Could you guys help me?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I'm trying to do the same thing and have the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

I've come across the need to test a class that implements ErrorHandler as well and went down the same path as you (but in my case a mock service that raised an error) and ran into the same problem of test exception forcing the test to fail. This is a text book example of needing to refactor to make something more testable.

It also hit me I wasn't JUST testing my implementation of **handleError()** but also angular2's ErrorHandler functionality. In other words the level of integration for the test was to high, I just needed to test my **ErrorHandlerService** service in isolation from angular2's error functionality.

This is what I did

```js
@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandlerService implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor() {}

  handleError(error: any): void {
    this.processError(error);
    throw error;
  }

  public processError(error: any) {
    console.log(error);
  }

}
```

and the test itself

```js
  it('correctly handles error', inject([ErrorHandlerService], (service: ErrorHandlerService) => {
    const spy = spyOn(console, 'log');
    const error: Error = new Error('ERROR');
    service.processError(error);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
  }));
```

You don't need to actually `throw new Error()`, The Angular2 team has already confirmed that for you.

Comment: This doesn't test that the handleError of ErrorHandlerService will get triggered whenever an App level error/exception happens. This is not a good unit test for the OP's question.

Comment: @blackspacer Why does it have to? It's a unit test, not an integration test which is what you're proposing. You're right in that it would confirm he has things configured correctly within Angular2's error API, but is it worth going to that effort? The end of the day the OP would have to weigh cost of setting up such a test against its inherent value. I was just proposing a compromise of isolating his logic away from that framework. Better to have some coverage as opposed to none

Comment: Thanks, I spent several hours on asking myself why the errors do not get recognised by my ErrorHandler and its handleError method. Just **testing the ```handleError()``` method directly** does the main part of what this unit test should do and saved me from spending more time on this than necessary.

Comment: Glad it was helpful, the end goal is to automate testing as much as possible, (integration and unit). But there are situations where it can get to costly for what value? You'd spend more time getting the test working and maintaining it than having it work for you. In this situation, a manual test covered by a QA test script can catch if you've wired your error handling correctly.

Comment: why is processError public?  It is called by handleError so it should be private.  In which case, your test would not work

Comment: Correct, won't work from an integration test perspective. 

The challenge here is attempting to build an automated test that throws an error without the test failing erroneously due to the thrown error. A prospect that is expensive to build with little to gain. So the compromise here is to just call handleError directly from unit test. Either through exposed public method, or directly depending on your coding standards.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two different testing scenarios:

One where you do actual unit testing of your "BkExceptionHandlerService", calling the "handleError" method directly, spying and mocking what you need to cover all the scenarios.

And an integration test where you actually overwrite the provider of "ErrorHandler" with your custom "BkExceptionHandlerService" and then you check that when you try to inject an instance of "ErrorHandler", it returns an instance of your "BkExceptionHandlerService"

For example (inspired from here https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3a60063a54d850c50ce962a8a39ce01cfee71398/aio/src/app/shared/reporting-error-handler.spec.ts), assuming that you are overwriting the dependency in your "AppModule"

```
it('should be registered on the AppModule', () => {
   handler = TestBed.configureTestingModule({ imports: [AppModule] }).inject(ErrorHandler) as any;
   expect(handler).toEqual(jasmine.any(BkExceptionHandlerService));
});
```

You really shouldn't test that when you trigger an error, your error handler catches it because you'd be testing the framework instead of your code.