# Angular Spectator Testing ErrorHandler HttpErrorResponse

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-spectator

**Summarize the problem:**
I want to test my custom ErrorHandler with Spectator and Jest. I expected to pass a simple test where a specific method `handleFailFastError` gets called one time for a `HttpErrorResponse` with status code `500`. Actual result is that the `HttpErrorResponse` gets handled as a `TypeError` within another method.

**Describe what you've tried:**
I checked if I am inside the method and yes I am. Checked with `console.log` calls and printed out the error. It is an `{castToWriteable: [Function]}`Object. In consequence my condition to check if it is an instance of `HttpErrorResponse`is failing and my handleError handles the Response as an TypeError. Orientated my self on this [example](https://gist.github.com/dirkluijk/3a29f5abc7e57d7e6e3b5788f462625c). Also checked this stackoverflow [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41323160/how-can-i-test-an-angular-2-errorhandler-implementation) out.

**Show some code**
ErrorHandler:

```js
    @Injectable()

    export class ErrorHandlerInterceptor implements ErrorHandler, OnDestroy {

    private _destroy$ = new Subject();

    constructor(
        private _injector: Injector
    ) {
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this._destroy$.next();
        this._destroy$.complete();
    }

    public handleError(error: Error | HttpErrorResponse): void {
        console.log('Did i get called?', error);
        const failFast: number[] = [401, 403, 500];
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            if (navigator.onLine) {
                        if (failFast.includes(error.status)) {
                            handleFailFastError();
                        }
                        if (error.status === 409) {
                            //handleConflictError();
                        }
                        if (error.status === 400) {
                            //handleBadRequestError();
                        }
                        //handleAnythingElse();
            } else {
                //Errors, when the user is offline
                //handleOfflineError();
            }
        } else {
            //Type errors
            console.log('Type Error',error);
            //handleTypeError();
        }
    }

    //functions
    public handleFailFastError(): void {
        console.log('Handled 500');
    }

    }
```

My test so far using spectator and jest:

```js
    import {ErrorHandlerInterceptor} from './error-handler.interceptor';
    import {createServiceFactory} from '@ngneat/spectator';
    import {createSpyObject, SpectatorService} from '@ngneat/spectator/jest';
    import {HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
    import {CoreModule} from '@app/core/core.module';

    describe('ErrorHandlerInterceptor', () => {
        const createErrorHandler = createServiceFactory({
            service: ErrorHandlerInterceptor,
            imports: [CoreModule],
            mocks: []
        });

        let specErrorHandler: SpectatorService<ErrorHandlerInterceptor>;
        const dummyError = createSpyObject(HttpErrorResponse);

        const handleError = (error: HttpErrorResponse): void => {
            specErrorHandler.service.handleError(dummyError);
        };

        beforeEach(() => specErrorHandler = createErrorHandler());
        it('should create the error handler', () => {
            const errorHandler = specErrorHandler.service;
            expect(errorHandler).toBeTruthy();
        });

        it('at least console should be called 2 times', () => {
            const spyConsole = spyOn(console, 'log');
            [500].forEach(status => {
                handleError(new HttpErrorResponse({status}));
                expect(spyConsole).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(5);
            });
        });

        it('should redirect, and delete sessionStorage', () => {
            [500].forEach(status => {
                handleError(new HttpErrorResponse({status}));
                expect(specErrorHandler.service.handleFailFastError).toBeCalled();
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried to console.log your error in the handler?

Comment: @Sergey yes as i wrote, it is turned into an `{castToWriteable: [Function]`

Comment: Looks like you get some kind of observable. Try to get type of error